# Restricting Notepad++ operations to occur in a range of lines

Tags: notepad++

With Notepad++ and the Find/Replace tool, is there a RegExp or another way to restrain the operation within a range of lines?

For example, let's say I want to find a string, replace with another string only in lines 40 to 50.

Answer (score 3):

You can manually select the range then replace strings using flag option "in selection"

[image]

Comment: That was so obvious !
Although I've just learnt that I could choose to print the Selection while I own a printer for years.
Thanks