# A regexp for a non reguser

Tags: notepad++

Gianluca Colombo recalled me the Selection checkbox to restrict replacement within a defined selection.
[Restricting Notepad++ operations to occur in a range of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26627921/restricting-notepad-operations-to-occur-in-a-range-of-lines)
I must give it that it was a silly request but this one seems tp me more thoughtful :
Is it possible to restrict replacement within a number of column ?

I found a code with all the line numbered.
I need to remove the numeric values but only in the 3 first columns.
http://samuel.dumont.pagesperso-orange.fr/file/col.png

Comment: since you want to work with only 1st column you can alternatively search for the new line character from the line above it and then replace it with the new line character and the replacement text that you wan to use. Note, this will not replace anything in 1st line and will make an extra replacement in the last line if you have an empty line at the end of the file.

Comment: I Googled a good answer. Rectangular selection with Alt :  
http://superuser.com/questions/339601/how-would-i-delete-the-first-27-characters-from-every-line-notepad
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**SynWrite** app can do it, maybe Notepad++ too. Try it. Select vertical block of 1st 3 columns (or N columns); on Replace dlg check option "In selection only".